# Migrating Large Content Web App to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have a large web app with around 20 gigabytes of images and mp3s.  It currently uses standard file IO libraries to read and write the sounds and mp3s.  I'd like to migrate it to Azure, but I have concerns about storing that much content.  Is it possible to use an App Service to host the web app and some sort of storage mounted to the root of the site for the assets without rewritting all of the file access to use blobs or some other api?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the App Service plans [`here`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/), you will notice that with `Standard` and better plans, you get storage more than 20GB (50GB+) so it is certainly possible to take your app as is and run it in Azure. However it is not recommended practice.

What you should do is make use of `Azure Blob Storage` for storing media content. You will need to make some changes as you can't simply mount Azure Blob Storage as a network drive.

There's [`Azure Files`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/storage/files/) as well that can be mounted as a network drive but as of today you can't mount a `File Share` as a network drive in an Azure WebApp. You would need to deploy your application in either a `Virtual Machine (IaaS)` or rewrite your application to run as a `Cloud Service`.